# How can I improve the performance and stability of my Ubuntu installation which runs slow and crashes at times?

Tags: freeze, performance

I recently switched from Windows and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my computer, but I have been experiencing slow performance and occasional crashes. Are there any solutions to improve the speed and stability of my Ubuntu installation, or would it be better to consider installing an older version of Ubuntu?

My specs are:

- 8GB RAM
- 250GB of Hard Disk storage
- AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon HD

Comment: It's a bit difficult to diagnose a problem without some specifics. Is there a repeatable way you can make the system crash? What exactly is slow? Can you be a bit more specific? In general though, no, running an older release won't make it crash less or be more stable. Although you don't say what release you're running, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: If your storage is an HDD rather than a SSD your system will be on the slow side for most things. I have a laptop with similar specifications and a SSD made a big difference. You haven’t said which version of Ubuntu you are using. If it’s Ubuntu GNOME then you might get some benefit moving to Xubuntu or Lubuntu.